# How to create a Gmail filter for multiple email addresses?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Gmail includes the option to create a filter that moves incoming messages to a folder based on the sender's email address.

[image: filtersettingspage1]

[image: filtersettingspage2]

How can the same filter be used for multiple sender addresses?

For example, if I want a filter to apply the same label to messages from multiple addresses such as naukri, monster, hirist, etc.

Commas/semicolons are not working.

Answer (score 7):

To make a filter work as long as one of the emails is present, use OR

> emailA@mail.com OR emailB@mail.com

The "OR" should be capitalized.

here are some more examples: [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

> Messages that match multiple terms
>
> OR or { }
>
> Example: from:amy OR from:david
>
> Example: {from:amy from:david}